# React-redux is not linking eventActions and eventReducer

Tags: react-redux

I am unsure what to do? I keep getting this error. When I use an action. I am assuming my `eventActions.js` are not mapping to the `eventReducer.js`!

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
E:/reduxbootcamp/revents/src/features/event/eventReducer.js:67
  64 | };
  65 | 
  66 | const deleteEvent = (state, payload) => {
> 67 |   return [...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload.event.id)];
  68 | };
  69 | 
  70 | export default createReducer(initialState, {
View compiled
deleteEvent
E:/reduxbootcamp/revents/src/features/event/eventReducer.js:67
  64 | };
  65 | 
  66 | const deleteEvent = (state, payload) => {
> 67 |   return [...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload.event.id)];
  68 | };
  69 | 
  70 | export default createReducer(initialState, {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
E:/reduxbootcamp/revents/src/app/common/util/reducerUtils.js:5
  2 |     return (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
  3 |         const handler = fnMap[type];
  4 | 
> 5 |         return handler ? handler(state, payload) : state
  6 |     }
  7 | }
View compiled
▶ 7 stack frames were collapsed.
EventDashboard.handleDeleteEvent
E:/reduxbootcamp/revents/src/features/event/EventDashboard/EventDashboard.jsx:77
  74 |  };
  75 | 
  76 |  handleDeleteEvent = id => {
> 77 |    this.props.deleteEvent(id);
     | ^  78 |  };
  79 | 
  80 |  render() {
View compiled
onClick
E:/reduxbootcamp/revents/src/features/event/EventList/EventListItem.jsx:45
  42 | <Segment clearing>
  43 |   <span>{event.description}</span>
  44 |   <Button
> 45 |     onClick={() => deleteEvent(event.id)}
     | ^  46 |     as="a"
  47 |     color="red"
  48 |     floated="right"
```

Here is my Github [repo](https://github.com/g1bbed/revents)

SO far I have searched over the documentation & looked over my code for errors. Below is the code I think is responsible. *Please note that I installed 5.1.1 `react-redux` over the newer 7+ version..*

```
const createEvent = (state, payload) => {
  return [...state, payload.event];
};

const updateEvent = (state, payload) => {
  return [
    ...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload.event.id),
    payload.event
  ];
};

const deleteEvent = (state, payload) => {
  return [...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload.event.id)];
};
```

Expected the action to just work once it was all connected to the event dashboard

Comment: Hello Claire, Welcome to Stack Overflow, and congratulations on your first question!  Would you be able to add the specific error message you are receiving to the question? It will help SO users identify the cause of your problem.

Comment: @TimOgilvy I updated the error message to include more information that is displayed in Chrome.

Comment: The GitHub repo you have provided doesn't have any code you have pasted in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` and by looking at your incriminated code:

```
const deleteEvent = (state, payload) => {
  return [...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload.event.id)];
};
```

...we can see that in only 2 places a property named `id` is accessed:

1. as `event.id`
2. and as `payload.event.id`

So either `event` is undefined or `payload.event` is.

The first scenario can happen if you have undefined values in `state` (which we can assume is an array). The second one usually comes from a bad use of action creators.

By looking at the stack trace we see this:

```
handleDeleteEvent = id => {
  this.props.deleteEvent(id);
};
```

That means that the only thing you pass to the action creator is the `id` itself.

You didn’t share the implementation of `createReducer` but we can infer it’s some kind of boilerplate helper. Usually the only argument of action creators exposed by such helpers is directly the `payload`.

So, could it be that the right implementation of your reducer is the following?

```
const deleteEvent = (state, payload) => {
  return [...state.filter(event => event.id !== payload)];
};
```

Comment: Thanks, It was the id :)